# Should I Change heroku app location from US to regional? If yes how to do it?

Tags: heroku

I have a basic application which was created with heroku but at the time of creation there was no mention about regions. As a result my application region is US instead of India.

Are there any problems by being in a region that I don't belong to? I've looked at herokus migration guide but I would like to avoid those many steps to achieve a region change.

Answer (score 0):

The speed of light is a problem.

If all your visitors are in India, but your server is in the US, then your site will be slower for those visitors. You might get a significant reduction in latency and increase in throughput by moving the site closer to its visitors.

Comment: Ok so is there a way to do it rather than follow the migration guide that heroku has? I can delete and create a new app and specify a region this time but do you by any chance know if there's a direct way to go about this?

Comment: I moved everything away from Heroku some time ago, so I don't know of any shortcuts, only following their official guides.